# Displaying HTML content via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I wonder, how can I display HTML content using Javascript, from what I know and been searching it's simply not possible to do that.

But I have found a javascript code, that is displaying HTML content (not raw) when there is `frame` in the URL parameters.

Here it is:

http://otslist.eu/ratingWidget.js - Here you can find the raw javascript code.

http://otslist.eu/ratingWidget.js?frame=1 - And here it is displaying the HTML.

How is that possible? How to do something like that?

Comment: Learn little more javascript...

Comment: It's not possible to display HTML using JavaScript? One of the primary uses of JavaScript is to manipulate the DOM - i.e. to display HTML. Start with a basic guide to JavaScript and DOM manipulation.

Comment: That code uses jQuery to manipulate the DOM, but you can do it with simple Javascript. Read up on it and you will be able to understand that code yourself.

Comment: You might want to improve your question, as your actual question seems something like "I see a *.js extension in the URL, but the page shows as an HTML page when I add `frame=1` to the URL. How is this possible?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript you see is a PHP script on the server. Use some browser/network debugger tool to check the HTTP response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Server              nginx/0.7.67
Date                Wed, 06 Jun 2012 11:50:44 GMT
Content-Type        text/html
Connection          keep-alive
X-Powered-By        PHP/5.3.10
Expires             Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control       no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma              no-cache
Content-Encoding    gzip
```

and see that it is powered by PHP. So it is the output of a PHP script and not a regular JavaScript document.

The PHP script outputs a JavScript when `frame=1` is omitted.
When the `frame=1` is included, it tells the PHP script to embed the JavaScript into an HTML page and serve that.

**Update:** The PHP script *could* look like this:

```
<?php
$asHTML = $_GET['frame'] == 1;

if($asHTML) {
  // Generate HTTP headers for HTML, like
  header("Content-Type", "text/html");
} else {
  // Generate HTTP headers for the JavaScript, like
  header("Content-Type", "text/javascript");
}

if($asHTML) {
  // Generate HTML top document part
  echo "<html><head><title>Title</title></head><body><script type=\"text/javascript\">";
  // Other HTML header stuff here as well, see the live example (as I am too lazy to type it here)
}

// Read the JavaScript from a file that is available on the server
readfile("javascript.js");

if($asHTML) {
  // Close HTML tags
  echo "</script></body></html>";
}
```

Note that I quickly typed this together, so it is probably full of errors. But it should give you the general idea.

Comment: I understand everything, but I just would like to see the code itself, how it is working (that js extension file is treated as a PHP file)...

Comment: Ok, as this is not too complex, I quickly typed some example code how this could be done.

Comment: Thanks, but how comes the script I posted in my question, has the `.js` extension? The code you gave won't be executed in the .js extension file. There is possibility that they are using mod rewrite in this case?

Comment: The script extension does not really matter. As long as the server uses PHP to parse it.

Comment: Then how can I parse js extension using PHP?

Comment: Check out [Serving pages without PHP file extension](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=59933) or google on 'apache php file extension' for more results. (Assuming you use Apache)

Comment: Have you got similar tutorials for lighttpd?

Comment: Replace apache by lighttpd in my previous Google search... Eg: [Lighttpd map html pages to php](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/lighttpd-map-html-pages-to-php-execute-html-pages-as-php.html). Using Google is not that hard...

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code of both pages, you will see that it is different code. The page with the frame parameter is HTML and the other is JS. So the server looks for the frame parameter and if exists serves the HTML page else the JS page.

try

```
http://otslist.eu/ratingWidget.js?frames=1
```

here the `frame` parameter does not exists (is frames with an s), so it serves the JS version

and try

```
http://otslist.eu/ratingWidget.js?frame=1515
```

here the `frame` parameter exists even if the value is 1515, so it serves the HTML version

also if you use 'Live HTTP headers' add-on of Firefox you will see that the response from the server for the first url is `Content-Type: text/javascript` and for the second is `Content-Type: text/html`

Comment: I understand everything, but I just would like to see the code itself, how it is working (that js extension file is treated as a PHP file)...

Comment: you need an ftp access at otslist.eu to see the source code

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing you point here but it seems like pretty basic javscript. The innerHTML-property can be used to manipulate what is contained in e.g. a div. For example

```
document.getElementById("changeMyContent").innerHTML='<strong>New</strong> content';
```

Have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp, they host a live example.

Comment: I understand everything, but I just would like to see the code itself, how it is working (that js extension file is treated as a PHP file)...